# Ignore font type when comparing strings

Tags: java, string, fonts

I have a foreign language dictionary that I load into a map which users will enter terms for translation against; it's every basic. However, I am running into an issue with the map look (map.get("term")) up because of the font types of both the user and of the dictionary (which is a flat text file); they are different and about 1/3 of the terms aren't found because of the difference of font. For example **(fonts don't show up so I included the uri encode value to show difference..URI encoding is not a solution I'm looking for)**:

```
String a1 = "A";// uri encode value \uff21
String a2 = "A";// uri encode value \u0041
Boolean a3 = a1.equals(a2);
System.out.println(a3); // false
```

The dictionary file is quite large and I don't have the luxury of data scrubbing before loading it into the map. I haven't been able to find any string function or API that will handle this sort of issue. Has anyone ran into this before and can anyone offer some ideas on how to compare strings while ignoring fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Java's Collator class:

```
Collator c = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
c.setStrength(Collator.IDENTICAL);
c.setDecomposition(Collator.FULL_DECOMPOSITION);
boolen a3 = c.equals(a1, a2); // should be true now
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html for more information.

Comment: Right on, I was looking in the wrong place: the java.awt.Font class wasn't doing it for me. Thanks for the nudge in the proper direction.

Comment: Yeah, it actually has nothing to do with fonts. Fonts are displaying the same Unicode symbol in different ways, here we are talking about difference Unicode symbols.